# How to toggle Object visibility driven by armature layer visibility using python?

Tags: python

@Jerryno

I want to hide or show mesh object depending on the visibility of the layer
I adapted your code. It's not working why ?

> On visibility of armature layer[0] the object ie Cube should be
>   visible and on hiding of armature layer[0] Cube should hide

[the test file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jpq2cgNh8zMnpaQS1JaVFBRHM/view?usp=sharing)

```
import bpy

class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, object, property, function):
        #if the property object needs deep copy
        try :
            self.oldValue = getattr(object, property).copy()
            self.newValue = getattr(object, property).copy()
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>> try  self.oldValue  >>>>>>>",self.oldValue)
        #if the property object doesn't need it (and don't have a copy method)
        except AttributeError: 
            self.oldValue = getattr(object, property)
            self.newValue = getattr(object, property)
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>>AttributeError  self.newValue >>>>>",self.newValue[0],self.oldValue[0])

        self.object = object
        self.property = property
        self.function = function

    #Call the function if the object property changed
    def update(self):
        if (self.oldValue[0] != self.newValue[0]):
            print(self.oldValue[0] , self.newValue[0])
            self.function(object=self.object, new=self.newValue, old=self.oldValue)

# this holds all the watchers
watchers = []
def add_watcher(object, property, function):
    watchers.append(Watcher(object,property,function))

# 
def visibility_change(object, new, old):
    print(object)
    print("old value: " , old[0])
    print("new value: " , new[0])
    if (new == True):
        bpy.data.objects["Cube"].hide = False
        return
    else :
        bpy.data.objects["Cube"].hide = True
        return

# Watch layer visibility
add_watcher(bpy.data.armatures["Armature"], "layers", visibility_change)

def watcher(scene):
    """This function will be run everytime after scene updates"""
    global watchers
    for watcher in watchers:
        watcher.update()
    return

# add handler if not in app.handlers
if watcher not in bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post:
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(watcher)
```

Comment: do you mean the object should be visible only when the armature object is visible ? also there's nothing in your code that is setting the visibility or you are doing is printing variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the goal you don't need script, you can drive the object visibility with classic driver.

1. In outliner right-click the object eye (or render) icon and select Add Driver:

   [image]
2. Setup the driver like this ('layers' is an array and 0 point to the first layer, the values are 0 (hidden) or 1(visible)):

   [image]
3. Now your object visibility is driven by the armature layer visibility. The driver will not update on it's own, you need to change the frame to see it in action.

Comment: @ Jerryno thanks. this worked. 
If it's not too time-consuming can you tell me what's wrong in the script?

Comment: @ashwin The problem with the code is in update(self) function. The values old and new are always the same, the if statement is never executed. The reason for that is you deleted the try-except part from that function that handles updating the old and new variables. Also probably this deleted part would need to be updated to handle arrays, but not sure about it.